# How to get git_remote_connect() http response code

Tags: http, error-handling, libgit2

In the case of a failed call to `git_remote_connect()`, is there any way to get the response HTTP response status code? I can use `git_error_last()` to get an error message of "unexpected http status code: " followed by the HTTP response status code, but I need some way to just get the status code, rather than get a string with the code embedded in it.

Looking at the libgit2 code at http.c, it seems like the status code is discarded and there is no way for the caller to retrieve it. If that is indeed the case, any instructions as to making a feature request and/or related pull would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can log the requests/responses using git_set_trace. Finer grained error reporting would still be useful though. For example recently when Github removed password auth their responses contained a useful message about why the request was rejected, which would be nice to forward onto users of applications.

Perhaps git_error could have another member with more detailed error information for each "klass" of error?

Comment: That's an option.  I'm somewhat worried about adding too much additional complexity to the error handling.  What's there is simple, but I haven't really felt the need for it to "grow up".  For this particular issue, my gut would be to add a new callback in the `git_remote_callbacks` struct, but honestly, since remotes are so abstracted from their underlying type, this is going to be a bit tricky no matter where it lives.  I regret that I don't have great guidance but I'd really love to see a proposal for a public API change if you had something in mind.

Comment: Good point. Most client-side errors are pretty straightforward to forward onto the user or enhance (I know what context I'm calling it in, I know the function name and I get an error code and klass). It's generally the error klasses where libgit2 is itself calling other APIs where I'd like more details (SSH/OS/HTTP). Recent example: "error authenticating: failed connecting agent" being forwarded from libssh2. This is not easy for a user to understand, and at the moment the best I can think to do is provide a link to an FAQ on common SSH issues when GIT_ERROR_SSH is returned (which is ok).